# Spring Boot Java 11 app won't deploy in google cloud

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, java-11

I am new to Google Cloud and I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot / Java 11 app in Google Cloud's App Engine but it's not starting up. I can see in the logs that it picks the Spring profile set in the environment variable but it stops right after that, then it start up again.
Please find bellow my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: java -jar myapp*.jar
env_variables:
    SERVER_PORT: ${PORT}
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prd
    JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx1g -Xms1g'
```

Comment: I have no idea how google works, but check the logs

Comment: Can you share more info? Are you using standard or flexible AppEngine? What do you mean when saying “it picks the Spring profile set in the environment variable but it stops right after that, then it start up again”,  the element of JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx1g -Xms1g' is not taken? The error comes with that element? Also you can check the [StackDriver Logs][1] following this instructions.
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/writing-application-logs#viewing_application_logs